# How can I configure the Google Maps api to show a white Google logo instead of the default version?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Is there an API setting to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting *any* style will turn the logo to white.

That is apparently a design feature from Google to have a more neutral logo aspect (probably in case you change the map colors, it won't "conflict" with your color scheme).

I am not aware of any documented way to specifically set the logo color, but according to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827269) (read the 2 comments from the Google assignee) you will get a white logo if you set styles, even to default.

Apparently, just passing an empty styles array works:

```
var style = [{
  "stylers": [{ 
  }]
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Good old Google with the esoteric documentation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm really unsure why, but adding this to the map's styles (and passed through `defaultOptions`) seems to make the logo white:

```
      styles: [
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels.icon',
          stylers: [
            {
              visibility: 'off'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```